# Do you build things randomly or wait for Palpatine's missions?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I'm asking because I built an Imperial floor right after the "imperial items" told me I have to build a new floor to progress. About 4 missions later Palpatine asked me to build a new imperial floor. I couldn't do it though, because it said I needeed to progress in the game before building a new one. Therefore I had to skip that mission and spend 2 precious bux.

So my question is: can I build a new floor whenever I feel like it or is it better to get it assigned as a mission and do it then? And I don't mean just imperial floors, but residential and commercial as well. Right now I have 11 floors so I'm just at the beginning and I don't know how the missions look later in the game...

BTW it's a bit annoying that the old man does't recognise that I just accomplished his stupid mission 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I'm not sure entirely since it just came out but I have been doing all the missions and I only built an imperial level when it was a mission. I have two imperial levels now and had no problem with it. At first I thought the missions would be a kind of tutorial to get you started but now it seems like they could be totally random to an extent

Comment: @Kecoey, if it is the Get a shop with all workers at skill nine, I had that problem. I directly transferred the last skill nine into the shop, and the emporer never figured it out. So I fired that last guy, gave it a minute, and then hired him again (instead of having him go directly from a shop to the new shop). Emperor instantly spotted the mission was done then.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, Kecoey and StarPilot. I wasn`t sure when the game was released, since I usually am the last person on the internet to find out, but your advice is good and reasonable. @StarPilot I had the same bug problem with the level nine workers mission, sometimes it doesn't work smoothly and sometimes Palpatine doesn't recognise the mission as done eventhough you just finished it. And I had to skip the mission where he asked me for 30 workers, because there was no reason to build 2 unnecessary residentials at the time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been building whenever I can, but I've only built imperial levels when I needed to because of the imperial objective. I decided to follow this strategy as the more non-imperial levels you have, the greater your passive money earned grows. Imperial levels only generate credits when you create all the required items on them, and that requires active play time. So they are non-earners when you aren't playing.

Answer (score 0):

I build the levels that I have bitizens waiting to inhabit.  i.e. If I have 3 food service 9s hanging out, I build a food level, etc.

The Emperor's missions don't pay nearly as well as those of the Imperial Quests offer by Darth Vader.  But, unfortunately, there are very few of those after you hit 9 Imperial levels.  They each pay very well, but after 3 or 4 100K+ credit payoffs, you're left with a "No more quests" page.

After you complete the tutorial, there is little or no reason to follow the Emperor's quests.  The game does not inhibit you from progressing in any way if you do not follow his advice.  You just don't get his Imperial kudos in the form of a lousy 600 credits.

I've also built some Imperial levels in an attempt to unlock scenes.  There are several scenes that are tied to those levels.